# Giving any NPM install command Having this error

Tags: angular, npm, frontend, command, npm-install

`npm ERR! code UNKNOWN npm ERR! syscall rename  npm ERR! path C:\Users\pratish.devangan\OneDrive - HCL Technologies Ltd\Desktop\GEINE UI\GEINE_Platform\node_modules\@babel\plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding`

`npm ERR! dest C:\Users\pratish.devangan\OneDrive - HCL Technologies Ltd\Desktop\GEINE UI\GEINE_Platform\node_modules\@babel\.plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding-kX6eCJ6w`

`npm ERR! errno -4094`
`npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, rename 'C:\Users\pratish.devangan\OneDrive - HCL Technologies Ltd\Desktop\GEINE UI\GEINE_Platform\node_modules\@babel\plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding' -> 'C:\Users\pratish.devangan\OneDrive - HCL Technologies Ltd\Desktop\GEINE UI\GEINE_Platform\node_modules\@babel\.plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding-kX6eCJ6w'`

`npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:`
`npm ERR!     C:\Users\pratish.devangan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-18T07_19_29_915Z-debug-0.log`

see the image of error here :-
[image]

Comment: There's no telling what the error is about without any more information. Have you tried running the command line tool as administrator?

Comment: It looks like you have something strange in the environment path or that you are using the oneDrive directory, first try to put the project in other location like c:\project\... if this dose not work then try to fix the npm environment path.